# Apache rewrite rule to add query string to a url from a folder

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, aem

I need to append all url's from a folder with a query param using Apache rewrite rule.
For this all url's starting with `/abc/def/xyz/` the url should be appended with `?v=2`

For example, `/abc/def/xyz/folder/test.pdf` should become `/abc/def/xyz/folder/test.pdf?v=2`

I tried with `RewriteRule /abc/def/xyz(.*) /abc/def/xyz/$1?v=2` but it is not working.

Comment: what do you mean by "it is not working"? Does the redirect happen but to a wrong url?

Comment: @mish no.. the redirect just does not happen at all with the above rule. What could possibly be wrong with this rule ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got it only slightly wrong (start of the pattern), try this:

```
RewriteRule ^abc/def/xyz/(.*) /abc/def/xyz/$1?v=2
```

Tested here:
http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/

Comment: This rule works partially. I realized that I need to redirect the URL also after including the query param. also, I may need to add the param only is it is not already present..